# The documentation cache is still being constructed... message won't go away in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I recently found out that trying to see the documentation on any method or property in Visual Studio just stopped working and it always comes with the message:
***The documentation cache is still being constructed.  Please try again in a few seconds.***
Before, it was just a second and then it worked, now it just won't show the documentation anymore.

How dows this documentation cache works but more important, what can cause it to stop working?.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: I get this all the time. Usually it shows up after a second, but occasionally it will hang until I reload the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation cache is built as a part of idle processing.  There are commonly 2 reasons why this operation may never complete

1. Some other plugin / component is hogging the processor or IDLE queue preventing the documentation cache service from completing.
2. The documentation is corrupt / deleted from the machine.  This is less likely as it's parsing files out of the framework directory.

Most likely case is #1. Have you opened up devenv.exe under task manager and seen if it's actively doing any work?

Comment: It was doing some cpu stuff, restarted and now it works. Appearently, some extensionhs I installed caused the issue. I will reenable them one at the time to see which one is the problem.